# Access - Set combobox selected item on form load

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have form1, which contains subformA and button1. When the user is viewing form1, selects a record in subformA, then clicks button1, a new form2 will display. On that form2, one of the records is a combobox (it is a bound control). I would like to go ahead and select whatever value was selected in subformA. It shouldn't lock to that value, just set the initial value. Also, the values in question are GUID fields.

On form2, I tried the following:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Me.combobox.value = stringfromguid(Forms!form1!subformA!columnname)
End Sub
```

But that didn't work. I also tried it without `.value` and that didn't do any better. I also tried putting in a `me.combobox.requery` to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does that "didn't work" mean? Be specific - is there an error message or an unexpected result. What is `stringfromguid` function - check to see what's going in and what's coming out.

Comment: It doesn't select anything, combobox has no value when the form loads.

Comment: @Dave did the combobox has multiple field values ? did this combobox is bound to any recordset?

Comment: Yes, it is a bound combobox. The combobox has two columns, bound to column 2 (the GUID).

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
Forms!form1!subformA.Form!columnname
```

see [Forms: Refer to Form and Subform properties and controls](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm)

And in case `combobox` has multiple columns, the bound column needs to be the GUID.

Comment: That isn't working. I'm assuming that the problem is when the user clicks on the command button, the focus is no longer on the subform, so nothing in there is selected?

Comment: [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx). Use the Immediate Window to find out. @Dave